# Element type within string

Tags: python, types

I have a string with some letters , exclamation marks and numbers. As in:

```
s='Hello World! 1,2,3!'
```

Is there any function or simple way of retrieving the count of each character type (str, int..) within the string?

**Solved as:**

```
 punc = string.punctuation

 def get_counts(s):
     dic = {"alpha":0, "numeric": 0, "punc":0}
     for l in s:
       if l.isalpha():
           dic["alpha"]+=1

       elif l.isnumeric():
           dic["numeric"]+=1

       elif l in punc:
           dic["punc"]+=1

    return dic

  s=u'Hello World! 1,2,3!'
  get_counts(s)
```

output:

{'alpha': 10, 'numeric': 3, 'punc': 4}

Thanks!

Comment: By element type, do you mean for each different character? Or each word?

Comment: There are no other types within the string. Every element of the sequence is just a one-letter string itself. If you mean digits, letters, punctuation, whitespace, etc.. you would have to specify exactly which character classes you want to distinguish.

Comment: There is no built-in function that will do this by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `string` module:

```
import string

punc = string.punctuation

def get_counts(s):
    dic = {"alpha":0, "numeric": 0, "punc":0}
    for l in s:
        if l.isalpha():
            dic["alpha"]+=1

        elif l.isnumeric():
            dic["numeric"]+=1

        elif l in punc:
            dic["punc"]+=1

    return dic

s='Hello World! 1,2,3!'
get_counts(s)

{'alpha': 10, 'numeric': 3, 'punc': 4}
```

Comment: you would need an extra elif clause if you want to count white space as its own type or along with punctuation.